# Is it possible to use an ASCII NUL as a search/replace delimiter?

Tags: vim, replace, delimiter

In other words, just as you can use `:s/x/y/g` and `:s|x|y|g` and `:s#x#y#g` so too, can you use `:v\0x\0y\0norm 0`?

Comment: Why would you want to use NUL?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, because the ASCII NUL works as delimiter in the C code base of Vim and so it will truncate the entered string.

Answer (score 0):

The text under `:help E146` describes the possible delimiters:

> Instead of the '/' which surrounds the pattern and replacement string, you
>   can use any other single-byte character, but not an alphanumeric character,
>   '\', '"' or '|'.

Note that `<Nul>` (shown as `^@` = CTRL-@) is internally represented as a *linefeed* (ASCII 10) (see `:help <nul>`), but you can enter it in the command line via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>@</kbd>.

Therefore, though you can type a substitution with `<nul>` separator chars, Vim will internally represent this with linefeed `^J` = `<NL>` characters.

Comment: `<C-@>` is the zero byte (`char2nr('@')` is 0x40, 0x40-0x40 is 0. 0x40 is the delta between alphanumeric and other characters and corresponding control codes: `char2nr("N")-char2nr("\<C-n>")` is 0x40). It is not an internal representation: C string can not contain zero bytes. Internal representation is newline: see `:h NL-used-for-Nul`. `<C-@>` (`^@`) is the display representation: e.g. try `:echo strtrans("\n")`.

Answer (score 0):

`% sub ^@will^@MY_new_TexT^@gc` works

[image]